# Get the latest document from a document library after performing a filter operation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am having a requirement to get the documents for particular a column in my doc lib. column name is  StdDocNum.

Am having 1000s of documents in my doc lib and I wanna apply ,  with this column along with  condition and  on this doc lib. Now  assume that I will be getting the 500 documents after applying this query.Now I want to filter the result set with having the same StdDocNum value.

ie, I have 500 documents in the doc lib . Now I want  to filter these 500 documents with stdDocNum="MyDocNum1" and stdDocNum="MyDocNum2" .

1) Would like to know how to get the the above condition in CAML.

2) now once I get these documents - assume - the number of documents which has StdDocNum=1 is 50

and the number of documents which has StdDocNum=2 is  100

I want to get the item which is uploaded recetly, ie, with 50 as the total number of documents i want to get a  single document which is LATEST.

And since i have 100 documents with stddocnum=2,  how to get the document which is uploaded recetly[last uploaded document - Modified By].

thnx

help is appreciated!

Comment: Try U2U CAML Builder https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1H-kV-5gwStUlF1OEdjWWJZNXc/edit?pli=1

Comment: My CAML Designer 2013 is stuck. i am unable to open the  url itself.